# Serilog: How to log object in enricher?

Tags: logging, elastic-stack, serilog

We use Serilog to produce json logs (i.e. each log entry is a json, not text). The benefit is they can contain objects. I use it for example to log C# exception object like this:

```
ILogger.Error("Something bad happened. {@exception}", exception);
```

This will emit all properties of `exception` object to the log. (The variable `exception` is of type `Exception` here.)

Now I am confused why there is no easy analogy how to do this in an enricher. Currently, we add exception to log in enricher this way:

```
LogEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty("exception", new ScalarValue(exception));
```

Of course, the `ScalarValue` converts the exception to a string. It looks like a json object inside doublequotes (a "stringified json").

Now, the problem is that when we put this to ELK (a software to monitor the logs and let us search in them), it complains about `exception` field having a different type and it says that it should be object as it was before, not string. (This is another topic - I found many repeated questions how to "solve" it in ELK. But apparently, it cannot be "fixed" in ELK, it should be produced always in the same format. So that's why I ask this question.)

I can't see any object-based analogy of `ScalarValue` in Serilog. `AddPropertyIfAbsent` doesn't accept the object directly, it wants `LogEventProperty` with `LogEventPropertyValue`. And this abstract class has a few implementations including simple value, array and dictionary, but none of them seem to emit the object the same way as `@exception` does. So I am wondering if this very common and basic scenario is not covered by Serilog, or am I just blind?

Comment: As a side note, you should really follow standard conventions with your variable casing, so it doesn't confuse others. Local variables and method parameters should be camelCased (`LogEvent -> logEvent`) and property names in Serilog should be capitalized (`@exception -> @Exception`). Of course, Serilog has a dedicated way to log exceptions, `logger.Error(exception "Something bad happened");` which you could use.

Comment: @mason I tried to put exception as the first parameter, but that emits only a short message to the log. We use custom exceptions and want their properties to be visible in the log as well.

Comment: Then you may want to look into [Serilog.Exceptions](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions), which will capture custom exception properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your enricher accepts an `ILogEventPropertyFactory`. You can do

```
logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("User", userDetails, 
                                                            destructureObjects: true));
```

and that will enrich it with a custom object.